# IEEE from Synopsys in GHDL : passed as option, but not correctly taken into account

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I am using GHDL simulator, but I cannot figure out how to use non IEEE packages like **std_logic_textio** (apparently coming from Synopsys), usefull for various parsing (hread in my case).

I have carefully compiled my code with an option to indicate that my ieee is the Synopsys version.

```
ghdl -a --ieee=synopsys system_tb.vhd
```

However, I still get an error :

```
system_tb.vhd:25:10:error: unit "std_logic_textio" not found in library "ieee"
system_tb.vhd:25:10:error:  (use --ieee=synopsys or --std=08 for this non-standard synopsys package)
```

The GHDL version I am using here :

```
GHDL 0.35-dev (2017-03-01-221-gf170a6e) [Dunoon edition]
 Compiled with GNAT Version: 4.9.3
 mcode code generator
```

How can I correctly compile my code ?

*Update* : here are some info on my GHDL installation, made from github archives :

- linux mint 18.2 Sonya
- **`which ghdl` returns** `/usr/local/bin/ghdl`
- **`locate std_logic_textio` returns** :
- /usr/local/lib/ghdl/src/ieee2008/std_logic_textio.vhdl
- /usr/local/lib/ghdl/src/synopsys/std_logic_textio.vhdl

*Update* : I also recompiled GHDL with llvm backend and got the same result.

Comment: Commit f170a6e does not match a ghdl [release](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases) (note there's one after commit f170a6e). Without specifying the platform nor supplying a [mcve] it seems std_logic_textio did not get analyzed (mcode version). An MCVe (`library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_textio.all; entity system_tb is end entity;`) should analysis (ghdl -a --ieee=synopsys) without error.

Comment: I don't blame you for asking... Documentation for GHDL is not good...

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem : I recompiled GHDL from sources, with LLVM backend. Then the problem appeared more clearly : apparently, my real problem was during Elaboration, and not Analysis...The message appearing on my terminal referred to the elaboration phase. I solved the error by adding the -e option to the elaboration phase.

**We also need to pass the ieee option during Elaboration (when needed during analysis)**

Concerning the mcode version, I cannot explain the reported behavior.

Comment: OTOH, if you use VHDL-2008, std_logic_textio is not needed anymore as these procedures are in std_logic_1164.   The VHDL-2008 version of std_logic_textio has aliases to the ones in std_logic_1164.

Comment: Your question isn't accurate nor is your answer authoritative. Is your reported ghdl version correct? The mcode version doesn't need an -e elaborate command (does not generate anything) and does require synopsys (--ieee=synopsys) passed with the run command (-r) - it's a just in time machine code generator. See https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/InvokingGHDL.html, search for mcode on the page. If you do use -e in mcode it does require synopsys.

Comment: @user1155120: well, I am trying to do my best to ask about this weird behavior. Yes, the versions presented in my question are correct. Besides, no syntax error or whatever. My only error (may be) was to answer my own question, after having a fresh new ghdl, recompiled from sources, and targeting LLVM. There -e is needed. Concerning the mcode, I have no explanation.

Comment: You show the analysis command and an error then produce an answer that the problem actually occurred latter during elaboration.  Without a proper problem statement no one else could answer. A Stackoverflow reader could not find the actual problem without reading your answer. It's not wrong to answer your own question. It's not a useful question without a clear problem statement and also demonstrates a lack of research.

Comment: I agree. What can I do ? Besides, there is a more philosophical problem : when requesting such help from SO, I can only report my problem 'as it appears', between my keyboard and my mind. The error is sometimes between these two ends.

Answer (score 0):

What do `which ghdl` and `locate std_logic_textio` report (if you're running Linux)?

```
which ghdl
/opt/ghdl/mcode/bin/ghdl
```

and

```
locate std_logic_textio
/opt/ghdl/mcode/lib/ghdl/src/ieee2008/std_logic_textio.vhdl
/opt/ghdl/mcode/lib/ghdl/src/synopsys/std_logic_textio.vhdl
```

which tells me that the relevant library sources are in the right place relative to the ghdl executable. And as far as I know, the mcode ghdl (which is a JIT compiler) doesn't build compiled .o files like the gcc and llvm versions.

So I'm guessing something went astray when you installed ghdl, and the std_logic_textio.vhdl source is either in the wrong place or missing altogether.

Update the question with paths to these objects, and your OS, and how you installed ghdl, (from [github](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl)?) and we'll see if we can get further.

Comment: Same relative paths... should be OK. .  Does Dave's (oops, user1155120's) MCVE fail the same way?

Comment: I now suspect the issue comes from "0.35-DEV" which is not the "release" version. I am just trying again with github release.

Comment: LLVM backend, once installed. the `locate` command should find matching .o files for each VHDL language revision. (Again, does the MCVE fail the same way? If not, double check your library/use clauses. Minimise your VHDL file and add to question)

Comment: I'v just used 0.35 latest release, compiled with LLVM backend. Correct install. Same error. Weird.

Comment: It's David not Dave. The llvm and gcc versions of ghdl require the -e --ieee=synopys argument but don't require it with the -r. I think Tristan added the --elab-run command to avoid the confusion. If you use makefiles the individual commands are useful and you can define command line arguments (I'm not a fan of ghdl's --gen-makefile generated makefiles).

Comment: The reason I'm not a big fan of --gen-makefile can be seen in IEEE Std 1076-2008  9.4 Static expressions, 9.4.2 Locally static primaries para 1 e.,  and 13.2 Design libraries. Library IEEE is intended to be a *resource* library and all the dependencies on source files are usually excess baggage.